# Best way to accomplish this: Imaging?

Tags: c#, wpf, imaging

I am reading ID tags for music files in my program. I am using Taglib sharp for this.

But what I have troubles with is when I'm reading the album-art tag.

I get the album art image just fine. But it's in System.Drawing instead of WPF's System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage. And from what I've seen; the "Image" control inside of WPF can't use system.drawing images as a source?

What I've been doing is to save a local image every time I select a new song, and loading Imagebox.Source with a bitmapimage URI of that local image. And I'm actually smart enough to understand that it isn't such a smart solution of the problem.

But how would I set the image without saving it to a file and then opening it again?

Like if there's a similar feature to winforms picturebox.image in WPF?

I hope you all understand what I'm trying to tell you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source library called TagDotNet that might be useful to you.

[SourceForge Page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tagdotnet/)